# Aggregate and $ne Not Working as Expected

Tags: mongodb, null

I'm trying the aggregation below, but do not appear to be getting the expected result using *$ne* and *null*.

I have tried other solutions like using a combination of *$cond*, *$not*, and *$eq* to no avail.  Using *$gt:[ "$unloadeddate", null]* seems to give some results, but that does not seem to be proper syntax and I am concerned it's not trustworthy to run properly over entire dataset.

Also, querying as follows:

```
db.getCollection('esInvoices').find({"esBlendTickets.loadeddate":{$ne:null}})
```

... returns results so not sure why the same query in the aggregate function not working.

Any help is appreciated!!

**The first part works...**

```
"unloadeddate": { "$switch": {
        branches:[ {
            case: {
                "$ne":[ "$esBlendTickets.ticketdate", null]
            },
            then: "$esBlendTickets.ticketdate"
        }, {
            case: {
                "$ne":[ "$esDeliveryTickets.ticketdate", null]
            },
            then: "$esDeliveryTickets.ticketdate"
        }],
        default: null
    }
},
"loadeddate": { "$switch": {
        branches:[ {
            case: {
                "$ne":[ "$esBlendTickets.loadeddate", null]
            },
            then: "$esBlendTickets.loadeddate"
        }, {
            case: {
                "$ne":[ "$esDeliveryTickets.loadeddate", null]
            },
            then: "$esDeliveryTickets.loadeddate"
        }],
        default: null
    }
},
```

**... but this second part (essentially the same logic except for the resulting value) does not work as expected...**

```
"stagename": { "$switch": {
        branches:[ {
            case: {
                "$ne":[ "$esDeliveryTickets.ticketdate", null]
            },
            then: "Invoiced"
        }, {
            case: {
                "$ne":[ "$esBlendTickets.ticketdate", null]
            },
            then: "Invoiced"
        }],
        default: "Invoiced-Only"
    }
}
```

**Complete Aggregation:**

```
db.esInvoices.aggregate([ {
    $addFields: {
        // A single invoice will not have both a blend ticket and delivery ticket associated so looping tough each case should work.
        "unloadeddate": { "$switch": {
                branches:[ {
                    case: {
                        "$ne":[ "$esBlendTickets.ticketdate", null]
                    },
                    then: "$esBlendTickets.ticketdate"
                }, {
                    case: {
                        "$ne":[ "$esDeliveryTickets.ticketdate", null]
                    },
                    then: "$esDeliveryTickets.ticketdate"
                }],
                default: null
            }
        },
        "loadeddate": { "$switch": {
                branches:[ {
                    case: {
                        "$ne":[ "$esBlendTickets.loadeddate", null]
                    },
                    then: "$esBlendTickets.loadeddate"
                }, {
                    case: {
                        "$ne":[ "$esDeliveryTickets.loadeddate", null]
                    },
                    then: "$esDeliveryTickets.loadeddate"
                }],
                default: null
            }
        },
        "stagedate": "$InvoiceHeader.InvDate",
        "stagename": { "$switch": {
                branches:[ {
                    case: {
                        "$ne":[ "$esDeliveryTickets.ticketdate", null]
                    },
                    then: "Invoiced"
                }, {
                    case: {
                        "$ne":[ "$esBlendTickets.ticketdate", null]
                    },
                    then: "Invoiced"
                }],
                default: "Invoiced-Only"
            }
        }
    }}])
```

Comment: So if all your variations of "code" do not work for you, then perhaps you might consider showing over people some "data" and see what they come up with. We don't need to see every single thing you tried. Just and attempt, some data to relate that to and an expected result which can be obtained from the presented data. Almost certainly someone will then see what you mean to do and show you a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Think I just ran into the same problem you were having. Using Mongo 3.4 at the moment. From what I can tell the *query* `$ne` behaves differently from the *aggregate* `$ne` when you are comparing it to `null`. Threw me off for a little bit.

Specifically, a `{ $ne: [ '$field', null ] }` predicate in the [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/#exp._S_ne) pipeline will return `true` when `$field` is `undefined`.

However, when using [queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) (not `$aggregate`), the `{ field: { $ne: null }` predicate will return `false` for those same documents when `$field` is `undefined`.

My work-around was to use a `$project` with `{ field: { $ifNull: [ '$field': null ] } }` in a prior step to turn `undefined` instances of that field into explicit `null`s, which will then make the aggregate `$ne` work as I needed. For whatever reason, [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) works with null, undefined, and missing fields. Not sure why `$ne` is different.

---

Here's an example to reproduce.

```
db.test.insertMany([
    { a: 1, b: 'string' },
    { a: 2, b: null },
    { a: 3 },
])

db.test.find({ b: { $ne: null }}, { _id: 0 })
/*
returns:
{
    "a" : 1.0,
    "b" : "string"
}
*/

db.test.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        a: 1,
        b: 1,
        switched: { $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: { $ne: [ '$b', null ] }, then: 'cased' },
            ],
            default: 'default',  
        }}

    }}
])
/*
returns:
{
    "a" : 1.0,
    "b" : "string",
    "switched" : "cased"
},
{
    "a" : 2.0,
    "b" : null,
    "switched" : "default"
},
{
    "a" : 3.0,
    "switched" : "cased" <--
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is missing fields are `undefined` while `null` fields are, well, nulls. When you write `"$ne":[ "$esDeliveryTickets.ticketdate", null]` you don't filter the former but only the latter.

But `undefined` is "smaller" than `null`. In order to filter them both you just need to make `lte`/`gt` instead of `eq`/`ne`. So this query returns all existing values:

See example:

```js
db.test.insertOne(
{
    "a" : 10,
    "b" : null
})

...

db.getCollection('mytest').find(    {},
    {
        "a" : { $lte : ["$a", null] },
        "b" : { $lte : ["$b", null] },
        "c" : { $lte : ["$c", null] },
    })

// {
//    "_id" : ObjectId("606724f38ec4d26b981b5a1c"),
//    "a" : false,
//    "b" : true,
//    "c" : true
// }
```

In your case:

```
"stagename": { "$switch": {
        branches:[ {
            case: {
                "$gt":[ "$esDeliveryTickets.ticketdate", null]
            },
            then: "Invoiced"
        }, {
            case: {
                "$gt":[ "$esBlendTickets.ticketdate", null]
            },
            then: "Invoiced"
        }],
        default: "Invoiced-Only"
    }
}
```

and this one returns only missing (or null) values:

```
"stagename": { "$switch": {
        branches:[ {
            case: {
                "$lte":[ "$esDeliveryTickets.ticketdate", null]
            },
            then: "Invoiced"
        }, {
            case: {
                "$lte":[ "$esBlendTickets.ticketdate", null]
            },
            then: "Invoiced"
        }],
        default: "Invoiced-Only"
    }
}
```